# How to auto create matrix from .txt file name?

Tags: matlab

I am reading  data from a text file and sort it with matlab. It works well with below script:

```
load 'con.txt';
A = con;
X = sortrows(A,3);
```

But I've got many similar text files to sort with different names. E.g. `con.txt`, `bon.txt`, `ton.txt`, etc...
As such, I have to replace the name of file (i.e. `load 'filename'`) to load, and replace matrix (i.e. `A='filename'`) each time when i run the script.
Is there any easier way so that I don't need to replace two lines and `A` will auto equal to `.txt` file name?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
fname = input('enter filename:', 's');
A = load(fname);
...
```

Comment: You probably mean `A = load(fname);`.  `load fname` only works if there are no output arguments.  Also, what is returned from `load` is a structure of variable names.  Using `sortrows` on a structure doesn't make much sense.